# Cython with pyqt signal

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, cython

I am trying to use parallel cython to run expensive function. I wanted to incorporate a signal into the class. as shown below:

```
cdef class A(QObject):

    finish=pyqtSignal(float)

    def counter(self, int count): # define the type of input

        # Define all variables
        cdef int x = 0
        cdef int i
        for i in prange (count, schedule='dynamic', nogil=True):
            if i>=5000000: # capture any error
                x=100
            else:
                x += i
                self.finish.emit(i)
        return x
```

But it raises an error saying, I can't use QObject with cython. Can anyone shows me how to use cython and pyqt together.

Comment: Why use a `pyqtSignal(float)` if you only emit integers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#subclassing

> If an extension type inherits from other types, the first base class must be a built-in type or another extension type

As far as Cython's concerned `QObject` is a mystery Python class and thus you cannot inherit from it in a `cdef class` (it probably also won't work as a second or subsequent base class, because it *is* ultimately written in C/C++, and multiple inheritance of such classes is practically quite limited in Python).

Make `A` a regular (not `cdef`) class instead.

---

Also emitting a Python-defined symbol is almost certainly going to require the GIL, so you won't be able to do it (efficiently) in your `prange` loop.